# error after applying a udf on a dataframe in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, error-handling, pyspark, user-defined-functions

PYSPARK VERSION 2.3.2

I have dataframe (df) in pyspark with the following schema:

```
>>> df.printSchema
<bound method DataFrame.printSchema of
DataFrame[id: string, 
          F: string, 
          D: string, 
          T: string, 
          S: string, 
          P: string]>
```

I have the following simplified UDF:

```
rep = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: x.replace(":",";"))
```

the I do:

```
df1 = df.withColumn("occ", rep(col("D")))
```

but after df1.show() there is error:

```
 df1.show()
 [Stage 9:>                                                       
 (0 + 1) / 1]19/08/23 23:59:15 WARN 
  org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: 
  Lost task 0.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 30, cluster, executor 1):
  java.io.IOException: 
  Cannot run program "/opt/conda/bin/python": 
  error=2, No such file or directory
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
  at .....
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
  19/08/23 23:59:16 ERROR 
  org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 9.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 350, in show
  print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
  py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o339.showString.
  .......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have something wrong with your installation.

```
  Cannot run program "/opt/conda/bin/python": 
  error=2, No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that an installed conda package has overwritten the default python, which caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is not in your code.

Check the version from Java JDK that you are using. What I know is that the `.show()` method is not compatible with Java JDK 11. If you are using this version, just make a downgrade to version 8. And don´t forget to configure correctly the environments variable for JDK 8.